# Find all msgstr which are either not empty or multilines using regexp in a po file

Tags: regex, translation, po

In a .po file, what regexp could I use to find out all `msgstr` lines being either

```
msgstr "some text"
```

or which spread on several lines:

```
msgstr ""
"some multiline text"
"goes here"
```

but not empty ones:

```
msgstr ""
```

?

For the moment I'm using this:

```
(msgstr "[\D\s]+")|(msgstr ""[\n\D\s]+")
```

But it's not fully working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all following lines should start with a double quote with at least a single character:

```
^msgstr (?:"[^"\r\n]+"|.*(?:\n"[^\r\n"]+")+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `msgstr`  Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group for 2 alternatives

  - `"[^"\r\n]+"` Match from an opening till closing double quote with at least one character other than a double quote or newline
  - `|` Or
  - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `(?:\n"[^\r\n"]+")+` Repeat matching 1 or more lines with at least one character other than a double quote or newline
- `)`Close the non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iwvNJE/1)

If the following lines can also be empty:

```
^msgstr (?:"[^"\r\n]+"|.*(?:\n".*")+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F0U7eq/1)

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm. And thanks for the detailed explanation, which I hope, will serve other people in the future.

Comment: @swiss_knight You are welcome. If you don't want to deal with escaped double quotes and the strings all start and close with a double quote, you can also use `^msgstr (?:".+"|.*(?:\n".+")+)$` https://regex101.com/r/tG8Vdn/1

Comment: Clean and efficient as always

Comment: Your second (but not your first) regex will match `msgstr ""\n""` not sure if that should be valid? https://regex101.com/r/2Y1nSe/1

Comment: @Nick All is well? That is what I got from this question, that the first line starting with `msgstr` should not have `""` But if there also should be at least one character, then that could be easily fixed by changing the quantifier to `+` of matching at least a non whitespace char in between like `^msgstr (?:"[^\S\n]*[^\s"][^\n"]*"|.*(?:\n"[^\S\n]*[^\s"][^\n"]*")+)` https://regex101.com/r/0dY57w/1 or a variation of that  :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird recovering from surgery after bike crash :( hence not much activity of late. I hope you're having a good new year. I wasn't criticising, just pointing out a minor difference in behaviour (I guess I was a bit terse, blame it on having to type with one finger :). As you say, easily fixed.

Comment: @Nick Sorry to hear that, I hope you will recover soon. Hopefully 2024 will be a better year to all of us :-)

Comment: Cheers to that!